# Cant change navigation bar height ios 11

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, ios10, ios11

I cant change navigation bar frame in ios 11.
Here is sample of my code for ios 10:

```
if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
    let frame = CGRect(x: navigationBar.frame.origin.x,
                       y: navigationBar.frame.origin.y,
                       width: navigationBar.frame.width,
                       height: navigationBar.frame.height + 100)
    navigationBar.frame = frame
}
```

ios 10 and ios 11 screenshots respectively

[image: ios 10 nav bar]
[image: ios 11 nav bar]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Changing the height of the UINavigationBar is no longer directly supported in iOS 11 (see [here](https://openradar.appspot.com/32912789), [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79632#241436) & [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88202#274620)).

The best you can hope for is to do something like having a view behind the navigation bar and removing the borders (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html) for customisation examples).