# Change Navigation bar height on iOS Xamarin Forms?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer, master-detail, hamburger-menu

How can I change Height of NavigationPage's Navigation Bar on iOS app in Xamarin Forms ? Actually I have a Master Details Page and I want to change NavBar Height on iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can change the default height of NavigationBar in iOS right now. You can check this answer for more information:

[cant-change-navigation-bar-height-ios-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102678/cant-change-navigation-bar-height-ios-11)

And it may work with earlier iOS version with solutions in this thread:

[how-can-i-change-height-of-navigation-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751366/how-can-i-change-height-of-navigation-bar-swift-3)

I would recommend you to hide the default NavigationBar in that page and add a custom NavigationBar there, then you can set any height you want to the custom NavigationBar.

In the Page, hide the default `NavigationBar`:

```
public AboutPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this,false);
}
```

And then add your custom NavigationBar:

```
<StackLayout>

    <StackLayout HeightRequest="150" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Orientation="Horizontal">

        <Button Text="Menu" HorizontalOptions="Start" Padding="5"/>
        <Label Text="I'm custom navigationBar" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

    </StackLayout>

    <Grid>
       <!--... my layout-->
    </Grid>

</StackLayout>
```

If you want to change the height of all the navigationBar in your project, you can have a basePage with custom NavigationPage there.

I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Custom-NavigationBar) and added the custom navigationBar in AboutPage. You can check it and feel free to ask me any question.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with second approach to create a custom nav bar for my app.