# How to increase the height of Navigation bar in xamarin forms : Android

Tags: c#, android, forms, xamarin

[image]

Please anyone suggest some answers.

Comment: Please provide your code and edit your answer according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Navigation bar height on iOS Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61784782/change-navigation-bar-height-on-ios-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `NavigationPage.BarHeight` to change the navigationbar height for android platform.

create a **AndroidNavigationPage** :

```
public class AndroidNavigationPage: Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage
{
    public AndroidNavigationPage(Page page)
    {
        On<Android>().SetBarHeight(450); //set the navigation bar height
        PushAsync(page);
    }

}
```

then you could call it like:

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage =  new AndroidNavigationPage(your page);

    }
}
```

the more you could look at [NavigationPage Bar Height on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/navigationpage-bar-height).